# How to add Notification Service Extension for Firebase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to follow the guide here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-image

I went to New > Target > Notification Service Extension (embedded this new target into the original target) and pasted in `NotificationService.m`:

```
@interface NotificationService ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^contentHandler)(UNNotificationContent *contentToDeliver);
@property (nonatomic, strong) UNMutableNotificationContent *bestAttemptContent;

@end

@implementation NotificationService

- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
    self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];

    // Modify the notification content here...
    self.bestAttemptContent.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ [modified]", self.bestAttemptContent.title];

    // Call FIRMessaging extension helper API.
    [[FIRMessaging extensionHelper] populateNotificationContent:self.bestAttemptContent
                                             withContentHandler:contentHandler];

    self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}

- (void)serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire {
    // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
    // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
    self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}

@end
```

I am now getting `Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRMessaging' in NotificationService.m`.

In `NotificationService.m` I tried to import similarly to my original target's `AppDelegate.m` where `FIRMessaging` is available and working with no issues:

```
#import "NotificationService.h"
#import <Firebase.h>
#import "RNFirebaseNotifications.h"
#import "RNFirebaseMessaging.h"
...
```

Then I get `'Firebase.h' file not found`. I am confused because it seems to work in the original target, and this notification service extension is embedded in that target. I have tried messing with `Header Search Paths` and `Framework Search Paths` without much luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added Firebase in your podfile for "Service Extention"?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I needed another target inside my Podfile! That worked and got me past the import error. Now I am hitting `sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension) - Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead."` with `FirMessagingRemoteNotificationsProxy.m`.

Comment: Cool. On which line you are getting this error?

Comment: `NSObject<UIApplicationDelegate> *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` I read Firebase upgraded it to not use `sharedApplication`: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/1503, but I am stuck on old version `5.4.0`. :C

Comment: No you can't access AppDelegate from "Service Extention". I also tried to use it for updating the batch count of Push notification, but to no use.

Comment: Were you able to get this going?  I'm having the same issue.  About to try to tackle this tonight.

Comment: @MichaelFever Yes - https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2432

Answer (score 5):

You just need to add below text in your existing podfile.

```
target 'NotificationImage' do
   pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

Then only you will be able to see that file you want to include in your project.

Comment: It does not generate NotificationService.m file? what should I do? manually create this file or something else. please help.

Answer (score 4):

Put in your podfile

```
target 'yourNotificationServiceTarget' do
   pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

After, put in your NotificationService.m

```
@import Firebase;
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who use Swift package of Firebase, you need to select Service Extension from targets and add FirebaseMessaging to Frameworks and Libraries section and then you can import FirebaseMessaging in your service extension file.
And then you can use it like this.

```
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging
class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
        
        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            // Modify the notification content here...
           // bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title) [modified]"
Messaging.serviceExtension().populateNotificationContent(bestAttemptContent, withContentHandler: contentHandler)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**(1)** Add `'Firebase/Messaging'` in your podfile. Don't add unnecessary pods in your App extension target as some APIs are not allowed by Apple in App extension e.g. `UIApplication.shared`. You may end up with lots of errors otherwise.

```
target 'NotificationServiceExtension' do
   pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

**(2)** Close the project and run `pod install`

Have a look at [this](https://therightsw.com/ios-multiple-targets-with-cocoapods/) tutorial for adding pods to multiple targets.

Answer (score -2):

**You have to install the `'Firebase/Messaging'` pod first.**
**Then add the following to the bottom of the pod file.**

```
target 'NotificationImage' do
  inherit! :search_paths
end
```

#### If that does not work, please write in the following way:

```
#Uncomment the following line if you want to add a global app version
#platform :ios, '10.0'

def shared_pods
  # your pods here
end

target 'YourProjectName' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  shared_pods

  target 'YourNotificationExtensionName' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
```